# Cant add album art work/ thumbnail to imageview

Tags: android, bitmap, uri, thumbnails, mediastore

I'm a beginner with java and am not really sure what I'm suppose to do.I'm trying to add the artwork for each song to the recyclerview. 
If I remove the line "albumCursor.moveToNext()" after "while{ ", it will add the same picture to every song. But if I leave the it, the app crashes. 
I think it crashes cause all the tumbnails it creates have the same name, but I cant figure out how to change that.

```
 public void getSongList() {
    //retrieve song info
    ContentResolver musicResolver = getActivity() .getContentResolver();
    Uri musicUri = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    Uri albumUri = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    Cursor musicCursor = musicResolver.query(musicUri, null, null, null, null);
    Cursor albumCursor = musicResolver.query(albumUri, null, null, null, null);
    songList = new ArrayList<Song>();



    if(musicCursor!=null && musicCursor.moveToFirst()
            && albumCursor!=null && albumCursor.moveToFirst()){
        //get columns
        int titleColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                (MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
        int idColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                (MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
        int artistColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                (MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
        int durationColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                (MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION);
        int albumColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                (MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM);
        int albumIdColumn = albumCursor.getColumnIndex
                (MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID);
        int thumbColumn = albumCursor.getColumnIndex
                (MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART);


        //add songs to list
        do {

            long thisAId = albumCursor.getLong(albumIdColumn);
            String img = albumCursor.getString(thumbColumn);
            File imgFile = new File (img);
            Bitmap thisThumb = (ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath()), 40, 40));

            long thisId = musicCursor.getLong(idColumn);
            String thisTitle = musicCursor.getString(titleColumn);
            String thisArtist = musicCursor.getString(artistColumn);
            long thisDuration = musicCursor.getLong(durationColumn);
            String thisAlbum = musicCursor.getString(albumColumn);
            //Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
            //int thisThumb = albumCursor.getInt(thumbColumn);


            songList.add(new Song(thisId, thisTitle, thisArtist, thisDuration, thisAlbum, thisThumb, thisAId));
        }
        while (musicCursor.moveToNext() && albumCursor.moveToNext());
    }

}
```

I want it to add the art work to all the songs, if you guys need more info or code, just ask.

```
    12-11 20:59:45.723 6137-6137/com.reaper.frag E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                           Process: com.reaper.frag, PID: 6137
                                                           java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                               at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:262)
                                                               at com.reaper.frag.Fragment1.getSongList(Fragment1.java:168)
                                                               at com.reaper.frag.Fragment1.onCreateView(Fragment1.java:88)
                                                               at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2261)
                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1419)
                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1750)
                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1819)
                                                               at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:797)
                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2590)
                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2377)
                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2332)
                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:2209)
                                                               at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:649)
                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:145)
                                                               at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1238)
                                                               at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1086)
                                                               at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1616)
                                                               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21040)
                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6460)
                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
                                                               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21040)
                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6460)
                                                               at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:719)
                                                               at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:791)
                                                               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21040)
                                                               at com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout.onMeasure(SlidingUpPanelLayout.java:803)
                                                               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21040)
                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6460)
                                                               at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:719)
                                                               at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:791)
                                                               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21040)
                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6460)
                                                               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
                                                               at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
                                                               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21040)
                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6460)
                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
                                                               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21040)
                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6460)
                                                               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
                                                               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21040)
                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6460)
                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
                                                               at
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it :). So if someone has the same problem, I've posted my solution below.
It does still take ages for the app to load all the pics, but it's a start

```
 public void getSongList() {
    //retrieve song info
    ContentResolver musicResolver = getContentResolver();
    Uri musicUri = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    Cursor musicCursor = musicResolver.query(musicUri, null, null, null, null);

    Bitmap thisThumb = null;
    byte[] art;

    songList = new ArrayList<Song>();
    if(musicCursor!=null && musicCursor.moveToFirst()){
        //get columns
        int titleColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
        int idColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
        int artistColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
        int durationColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION);
        int albumColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM);
        int columnIndex = musicCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow
                (MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);

        //add songs to list
        do {

            String pathId = musicCursor.getString(columnIndex);
            Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "path id=" + pathId);

            metaRetriver.setDataSource(pathId);

            try {
                art = metaRetriver.getEmbeddedPicture();
                BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                opt.inSampleSize = 2;
                thisThumb = (BitmapFactory .decodeByteArray(art, 0, art.length,opt));

                //Bitmap thisAThumb = (ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath()), 40, 40));
                System.out.println("art `" + thisThumb+"`");

            } catch (Exception e) {
                //imgAlbumArt.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
            }
            long thisId = musicCursor.getLong(idColumn);
            String thisTitle = musicCursor.getString(titleColumn);
            String thisArtist = musicCursor.getString(artistColumn);
            String thisDuration = musicCursor.getString(durationColumn);
            String thisAlbum = musicCursor.getString(albumColumn);
            songList.add(new Song(thisId, thisTitle, thisArtist, thisDuration, thisAlbum, thisThumb));
        }
        while (musicCursor.moveToNext());
    }
}
```